# postgres 11, pg_xact, is it possible to purge very old files?

Tags: postgresql, transaction-log

Under PGDATA, there is the pg_xact directory containing the transaction logs.
Every night we stop and restart the postgresql daemon.

We have no replicas.
We have files older than *a month* in this directory.

1. Is this normal or is it a symptom of some problem?
2. Does a night VACUUM delete all these files?

Comment: Never delete files in the data directory yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal.  The files stick around until all tables have been frozen up to the point covered by the files.

You can encourage those files to go away by [lowering the setting of  autovacuum_freeze_max_age](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-WRAPAROUND) or by doing manual VACUUM FREEZE on the tables with the oldest freeze age. But there probably isn't much point.  Are the files taking up an unreasonable amount of space?